# Autocomplete combobox maintaining character case

Tags: .net, winforms, autocomplete, combobox

I have a control that inherits from a combobox and uses its capabilities to Autocomplete, Suggest and Append to show the user the top 10 most used names in our country that starts with the text that the user introduced.

In order to explain what I vant to change I will use an example:

1.- The user enters the text "dav" in the comobo (not a single Uppercase letter).

2.- The combo searches for the top 10 most used names and comes with a list (like the following image)

[image]

3.- When You access the Mybase.Text the combo will return you "Dav" with the first letter capitalized. Like you can see on the image above this lines.

**What I vant is the combobox to mantain the text entered for the user without any modificacion, no capitalizations**. Like this:

[image]

For what I tested the change occurs when the original Combobox control matches the text entered with the options on the dropdown list. If the text on the list matches the text entered by the user but there are some case diferences, then the text on the combo is changed to match the one on the autocomplete list.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the opposite problem. I had an `on change` event attached to my combo which required another combo. This made my combo keep the case of the typed text which I did not want. Solved it by changing to `On lost focus`

Hope this helps